# Error Running Python Script from Batch File from the remote machine FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '[]'

Tags: python, batch-file, batch-processing, remote-server

I have a python script in a server. I am able to execute this from the local server using a batch script. But when I try to execute this same batch file from remote server I get this error.

**"can't open file 'E:\test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"**

This is the bat file we are using. In place of servername we have the server where the test.py file is placed.

```
@echo off
pushd "\\servername\c$\"
"Program Files\Python310\python.exe" "E:\test.py"
```

Note: When I run this:

```
@echo off
pushd "\\servername\c$\"        
"Program Files\Python310\python.exe"
```

Python is opened with the same version that I have in the local server. I tested with os.listdir(/) all the files in the C drive of that local server gets printed.

Could someone please help here.

Thanks in advance

I want the python file to be executed from the remote machine using batch script.

Comment: Why do you `pushd` to a unc path and then try and run the file on ```e:\``` is the UNC path mapped as ```E:\```?

Comment: Surely the obvious thing to do would be to use `os.listdir()` with ```E:\\```/```E:/``` to confirm that `test.py` is displayed. Anyhow, I'm not sure why you're wanting to `pushd` to the `C$` if the file you wanted was in its `E:` drive!

Comment: thank you! Yes I missed that. It is working now.